# How can a cloned app with a different package name use Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I found out a copy of my app on the Google Play store - my APK with a different package name, app icon, and in-app images.

I assume the uploader used some apk tool to change these images and the package name somehow.
But how can an app with a different package name use the original's Firebase project? Afaik we need to declare allowed package names on the Firebase project console, and have a google-services file that declares that as well?

The app was developed with Flutter, don't think that matters.